# How can I prove $(P \to Q) \to (\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$?

Tags: first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I'm struggling to grasp how to do natural deduction and am going through questions but this one has stumped me completely.

The question is to prove $(P \to Q) \to (\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$ without the use of (non-discharged) assumptions.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know I need to start with assumptions in [ ] but I think I just can't grasp how and when to use the rules and I'm struggling to find any good resources online to explain them

Comment: If you get stuck at one point, always go back to your definitions of your objects, maybe plug them in, and try to understand what the problem is asking.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove $A\rightarrow B$ we have the rule $\rightarrow-$introduction which works that you assume $A$ and then prove $B$. In this case you want to prove 
$$(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P).$$ Thus assume $P\rightarrow Q$ and try to prove $\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P$. Again we can apply the reasoning above. Since we want to prove $\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P$ we assume $\neg Q$ and try to prove $\neg P$.

So at this point we have done two assumptions: $(P\rightarrow Q)$ and $\neg Q$. If we from this can prove $\neg P$ we can use two cases of $\rightarrow-$introduction and we will be done.

To prove $\neg P$ we have the rule $\neg-$introduction. Which works as follows: Assume $P$, derive a contradiction ($\bot$) and you may then conclude $\neg P$. **Can you take it from here?**